# React useState with Objects: Save dialog shows the fields are empty

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-functional-component

Could someone explain to me, why this is not working. I know that `setTitle` and `setDescription` are executed. How could I solve that?

Output on console

[image]

```
const FilmCreate = (props) => {
  const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false);
  let [film, setFilm] = useState({
    title: "",
    description: "",
  });
  let [title, setTitle] = useState("");
  let [description, setDescription] = useState("");

  const saveDialog = () => {
    setFilm((q) => ({
      title: title,
      description: description,
    }));
    console.log("before create");
    console.log(film);
    console.log("after create");
    close();
  };

  const changeTitle = (event) => {
    setTitle(event.target.value);
  };
  const changeDescription = (event) => {
    setDescription(event.target.value);
  };

  const close = () => setShowModal(false);

  const open = () => setShowModal(true);

  return (
    <div>
      <Button color="primary" onClick={open} className="float-right">
        Add Film
      </Button>
      <Modal isOpen={showModal} toggle={close} size="lg" autoFocus={false}>
        <ModalHeader toggle={close}>Show Film</ModalHeader>
        <ModalBody>
          <Form>
            <FormGroup row>
              <Label md={2} for="formTitle">
                Title
              </Label>
              <Col md={10}>
                <Input
                  type="text"
                  id="formTitle"
                  onChange={changeTitle}
                  value={title}
                />
              </Col>
            </FormGroup>

            <FormGroup row>
              <Label md={2} for="formDescription">
                Description
              </Label>
              <Col md={10}>
                <Input
                  type="text"
                  id="formDescription"
                  onChange={changeDescription}
                  value={description}
                />
              </Col>
            </FormGroup>

            <FormGroup>
              <Col className="clearfix" style={{ padding: ".2rem" }}>
                <Button
                  className="float-right"
                  color="secondary"
                  onClick={saveDialog}
                >
                  Save
                </Button>
              </Col>
            </FormGroup>
          </Form>
        </ModalBody>
      </Modal>
    </div>
  );
};

export default FilmCreate;
```

I tried to add a log in the `setTitle` and `setDescription` Method. But there the values are set. I also see that in the input fields of this fields.

Answer (score 1):

Usestate is asyncrhonous, have you tried to console.log(film) outside `saveDialog()` ?
The values inside `setTitle` and `setDescription` are set because they are triggered on a `onChange`, so each time you press a key the value is updated when saveDialog is triggered on a `click`.
Althlough I don't know exactly know what you want to achieve but you can try to use `useEffect` like this :

```
const saveDialog = () => {
  setFilm({                      // Asynchronous operation
    title: title,
    description: description,
  });
};

useEffect(() => {
  if (film.title && film.description) {
    close();
  }
},[film])               // Wait for film to be updated to execute another action
```

Comment: I use a modal dialog from Bootstrap. So if the user click the save-button, I want that the parent method is called. This method saves this entry in a list. But I always got an empty film object. So I left the call on the parent method out to show, that the object is always null. Is there another way to await that operation?

Comment: @Tempo useEffect is made for that. I added a condition in the exemple for you to execute code when film is defined. You can still share more code if needed